# Avoiding first zero in SQL Lag() and Diff calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table showing number of new customers, and number of returning customers:

```
fact_date   NewCustomer ReturningCustomer
01/08/2022  10000       0
02/08/2022  0           9944
03/08/2022  0           9894
04/08/2022  0           9842
05/08/2022  0           9803
06/08/2022  0           9748
07/08/2022  0           9707
08/08/2022  0           9654
```

I am trying to create a difference column to calculate churn.

```
select *,
lag(ReturningCustomer,1) over (order by fact_date) as PrevDay,
ReturningCustomer - lag(ReturningCustomer,1) over (order by fact_date) as Diff 
from table
order by fact_date
```

Which gives me:

```
fact_date   NewCustomer ReturningCustomer   PrevDay Diff
01/08/2022  10000       0                   NULL    NULL
02/08/2022  0           9944                0       9944
03/08/2022  0           9894                9944    -50
04/08/2022  0           9842                9894    -52
05/08/2022  0           9803                9842    -39
06/08/2022  0           9748                9803    -55
07/08/2022  0           9707                9748    -41
08/08/2022  0           9654                9707    -53
```

However you can see the second date shows a "diff" of `9,944`. But really it should be `-56`. Because the first day had `1000` customers and on the second day we lost `56` customers.

How can I make sure the Diff value is 56?

I have tried playing with case statements, default values for the lag etc. but it's a complete mess.

Comment: I don't see the point of having 2 separate columns for new and returning customers.  Why not just maintain one column?

Comment: select ReturningCustomer - case when lag(newcustomer) over(order by fact_date) > 0 then lag(newcustomer) over(order by fact_date) else lag(ReturningCustomer) over(order by fact_date) from yourtable

Comment: @siggemannen I couldn't get this to work. Incorrect syntax error.

Comment: oops, i misplaced and END just before FROM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this possibly a better solution?

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT fact_date, 
         Newcustomer, 
         ReturningCustomer, 
         LAG(Newcustomer + ReturningCustomer) OVER (ORDER BY fact_date) AS PrevDay
  FROM tab
)

SELECT fact_date, 
       Newcustomer, 
       ReturningCustomer, 
       PrevDay,
          CASE WHEN PrevDay IS NULL THEN NULL 
          ELSE Newcustomer + ReturningCustomer - PrevDay END AS Diff
FROM cte
ORDER BY fact_date;
```

It would be way more easier to use just one column instead of `NewCustomer` and `ReturningCustomer`.
Now, when you add e.g. 10 `NewCustomer`s it takes that into account.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lP65-BIE)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Here `diff` is difference in total number of Customers (NewCustomer+ReturningCustomer). If necessary, take (ReturningCustomer) only.

```
select *,
   lag(NewCustomer+ReturningCustomer,1,0) 
            over (order by fact_date) as PrevDay
  ,(NewCustomer+ReturningCustomer) - lag(NewCustomer+ReturningCustomer,1,0) 
            over (order by fact_date) as Diff 
from test
order by fact_date
```

Query result

| fact_date | NewCustomer | ReturningCustomer | PrevDay | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-08 | 10000 | 0 | 0 | 10000 |
| 2022-02-08 | 0 | 9944 | 10000 | -56 |
| 2022-03-08 | 0 | 9894 | 9944 | -50 |
| 2022-04-08 | 0 | 9842 | 9894 | -52 |
| 2022-05-08 | 0 | 9803 | 9842 | -39 |
| 2022-06-08 | 0 | 9748 | 9803 | -55 |
| 2022-07-08 | 0 | 9707 | 9748 | -41 |
| 2022-08-08 | 0 | 9654 | 9707 | -53 |